# Как узнать позицию клика и занести данные в переменную?

Tags: jquery

Только как узнать, относительно определенного блока? По классу например. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот на картинке блок длиной, приблизительно, в 450px и когда я нажимаю и попадаю на его область, от отчёт идет не от начала документа, а от начала блока? По оси X.
Как узнать значение X и занести его в переменную jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var corX;
$('div').click(function(event) {
  corX = event.offsetX;
  console.log(corX)
})
```

```css
.div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо!